# Connecting to different OpenVPN servers

Tags: vpn, vps, openvpn

I have set up two different OpenVPN servers, one in the US and one in London. I connect to them from home using Windows 7, and the software I use is the basic OpenVPN client.

Now the problem I have is that the client only has 1 single config directory, so when I put the files for my London server I can only connect to that one. To connect to the server in the US I have to switch files.

I do not have the option to use the client for the OpenVPN Access Server. I have set up the OpenVPN installation manually. The client from OpenVPN AS does not connect.

Anyone know of a OpenVPN client that handles seperate connections to different servers.

Comment: If you want to connect to several at the same time you will need to create some additional [TAP devices](http://serverfault.com/questions/155299/how-to-connect-multiple-vpns-using-openvpn-on-windows-7-on-the-same-time/155329#155329).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular [OpenVPN client](http://openvpn.net/index.php/openvpn-client/downloads.html) has syntax

```
openvpn [server config file]
```

So nothing stopping you from having two shortcuts, one for

```
openvpn LondonIPorFQDN London.ovpn
```

and

```
openvpn USIPorFQDN US.ovpn
```

Comment: Ok yeah this had to be possible. But where do I specify openvpn [server config file]. Is this in the windows shortcut? And do I just store all the files for all the servers in the config file. There are some duplicate files.

Comment: Yes, the windows shortcut, test with command line. Location of files is at your disposal; you really need to read the documentation for OpenVPN and understand the purpose (and security) of each key file and config file, especially if you are designing the VPN.

Comment: In fact, if you use the Windows client, and you have multiple config files in the config directory, it will show them as separate connection options when you right click on the tray icon.

Comment: it is much tidier to have only the ovpn files in the config directory and place the ca.crt and key files in subdirectory, one for each vpn the set the details in the ovpn to the directories